# Sometimes, map is a sequence, sometimes not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In python3, when I try to execute the following lines:

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 18 2014, 02:00:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD]] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def fail(arg):
...   raise Exception
... 
>>> def fail_type(arg):
...   raise TypeError
... 
>>> identity = lambda x: x
>>> m = [0,1]
>>> print("{:8.2f}{:8.2f}".format(*map(identity, m)))
    0.00    1.00
>>> print("{:8.2f}{:8.2f}".format(*map(fail, m)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fail
Exception
>>> print("{:8.2f}{:8.2f}".format(*map(fail_type, m)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: format() argument after * must be a sequence, not map
>>> list(map(identity, m))
[0, 1]
>>> list(map(fail, m))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fail
Exception
>>> list(map(fail_type, m))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fail_type
TypeError
>>>
```

Why does python throw that in my opinion highly misleading `TypeError: format() argument after * must be a sequence, not map` for this builtin function? It makes it even more confusing to see that an explicit `raise` for other `Exception`s is caught an passed through. Is there an assumption in `*` error handling that a `TypeError` must be due to the argumentlist not being a sequence?

Comment: try `del map`, you might have declared something with this name

Comment: Using `*map(...)` works for me, with the built-in Python 3`map()` function. Are you certain you didn't rebind `map()` to something else?

Comment: It's interesting, when I'd tried to run it with ipython I got [this traceback](http://pastebin.com/v4DuSfR8). But that was with scipy that come with ipython3, that was not visible to standard /usr/bin/python3. After installing from ubuntu repo I have the same results, both in ipython3 and 'standard' Python3 interpreter.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. If you cast map to a list, you get the TypeError exception.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I can't reproduce it on Python 3.2-3.4.

Comment: Unrelated: `map` doesn't return a sequence in Python 3. `map` object is not a sequence e.g., no `len()` method. It is an iterator

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian https://gist.github.com/burhan/9685775

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I admit that title is misleading (although in terms of duck typing, if `…(*…)` says it accepts “sequences” and accepts `map` objects, that's enough reason for me to call `map` a sequence in this context), but it's the kind of title I was looking for when I encountered the problem, so I deemed it helpful.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I can get `format() argument after * must be a sequence, not map` but not `'int' object is not iterable`. You don't need scipy to demonstrate it, just use `fail_type()` function. It is best to avoid giant dependencies if possible

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Oh, sorry, the `'int' object is not iterable` is due to my incomplete editing and improper proofreading. Fixed it, this is the copied output of a test run, so it should not contain any mistakes I made when moving it over here.

Comment: note: you don't need `format()` function. I can reproduce it with `f = lambda a: None; f(*map(fail_type, [0]))` It looks like a bug in Python

Comment: `f(*(fail_type(x) for x in [0]))` produces `argument after * must be a sequence, not generator` i.e., `map` is not the culprit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TypeError` exception match occurs in [`ext_do_call`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Python/ceval.c#l4463) (Python/ceval.c, line 4507), which is called to handle the opcodes `CALL_FUNCTION_VAR`, `CALL_FUNCTION_KW`, and `CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW`. It's assuming [`PySequence_Tuple`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Objects/abstract.c#l1646) raised the `TypeError` because the argument wasn't iterable, as is raised by [`PyObject_GetIter`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/04f714765c13/Objects/abstract.c#l2644).

There is an opened Python bug in "patch review" stage for 3 years: [Function calls taking a generator as star argument can mask TypeErrors in the generator](http://bugs.python.org/issue4806)

Comment: I've added link to the corresponding Python bug

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks. The patch would solve this problem. It adds an additional check for `(Py_TYPE(stararg)->tp_iter == NULL) && !PySequence_Check(stararg))`. So it would no longer match the `TypeError` raised by `fail_type`, since `map` defines `tp_iter`.

Comment: yes. It inlines one branch that leads to TypeError in `PyObject_GetIter()`. It ignores the other branch that tests whether `__iter__` returns an iterator.